# Why aren't these non-capturing regex groups working right?

Tags: regex, matching

So I spent a lot of time on another stack overflow question, and the same problem came up with a previous one.  Non-capturing groups aren't working as I'd expect them to, or so I believe.

This is a silly example along the lines of someone else's CSS test string...

Here's my regex:

```
(?:(rgb\([^)]*\)|\S+)(?:[ ]+)?)*
```

And here's the test string:

```
1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255) test rgb(255, 255, 255)
```

I'm expecting match groups of "1px","solid", "rgb(255, 255, 255)", "test", "rgb(255, 255, 255)"

But I'm only getting the last token matched.

This is the link for testing:

http://regex101.com/r/pK1uG7

What's going wrong here?  I thought I had non-capturing groups down, and the way it's explained at the bottom of regex101 makes sense, including the "greediness".

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/kW7uE6

Comment: Have a look at option g

Comment: I know how to do it that way.  There's nothing related to this that I actually need to do :)  ... aside from it being a learning exercise.  I'm trying to understand why I can't reliably use non-capturing groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The capture group overrides each previous match. Capture group #1 first matches "1px", then capture group #1 matches "solid" overwriting "1px", then it matches "rgb(255, 255, 255)" overwriting "solid", etc.

Comment: Darn it, regexes would have been much more fun if you could repeat capturing groups.  You're right though.  Oh well.

Comment: There are a lot of different rules for different regex languages. You might be able to in one of them: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines

Comment: As others have said, you can use the g (global) option to accomplish what your trying to do, the problem isn't to do with the non-capturing groups.

Comment: @graeme, /g isn't a silver bullet though.  You'd have a lot more flexibility if you can specify how many matches of a group to capture.  For instance, one of these, two of these, and 3-5 of those.  While you can capture a repeated expression, you then have to further parse the sub-expression on a second pass.  Which is understandable, but it's the poop in my regex party.

Comment: @sdanzig Only .NET can match repeated groups, see this [extensive answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406). I've also [stumped onto this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587023/capture-multiple-subgroups-of-repeated-group#comment18631689_13587023) which says that a certain implementation of Python supports it too.

Comment: @HamZa Well, I'd never choose .NET willingly, but that Python library makes me like Python just a bit more :)  But I don't want to make a habit of something that's generally not supported.  Regex muscle-memory should be portable.  I also worry about performance implications of supporting that.

Answer (score 2):

For this you would want to use the global option:

```
/(rgb\([^)]+\)|\S+)/g
```

http://regex101.com/r/kF2uV4

Non-capturing groups eliminate their results from the groups.
So if you want to match:

```
"1px","solid", "rgb(255, 255, 255)", "test", "rgb(255, 255, 255)"
```

Then you don't want to use capturing groups that way.

See: [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group)

See the answer of Ricardo Nolde at the top.
You're eliminating the ones you say you want back.

Comment: Yeah, my misunderstanding didn't have anything to do with non-capturing groups.  @graeme couldn't have been any more on point than he was :)

Comment: I'd kill my post, but you're title header might bring people that need it. It's a good question you asked.